# Is it meaningful to order infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ by probabilistic density?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is based on a recent question where is was pointed out that the probability of finding a prime tends to 0 as you move into larger and larger numbers.

Conversely the probability of finding a composite number tends to 1.

Even though both the set of prime numbers and the set of composite numbers are countable from a cardinal sense. It seems that it may be possible to order subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ by comparing the probability of encountering an element.

Is there a name for the “size” of a set in this context?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: Note that not every set has a well-defined density.